# Call C++ method from Java class?

Tags: java, android, c++, class

I make applications using an engine that generates Xcode or Android Projects and I primarily use Xcode for my projects. However I am looking to use Android Studio for the first time.

In the generated Android Studio project I have a `PTServicesBridge` Class where I add my own code for additional features outside the engine. (In this instance I need to adjust a score variable up but 1).

**PTServicesBridge Class:**

```
public class PTServicesBridge
    public static PTServicesBridge instance() {
        if (sInstance == null)
            sInstance = new PTServicesBridge();
        return sInstance;
    }

    public static void initBridge(Cocos2dxActivity activity, String appId){
        //some initialisations
    }

    //...

    public static void adjustScoreUp(){
        //I need to call a function from here <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    }
}
```

The project includes a `main.cpp` file that includes the method I need to call.

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "screens/PTPScoreController.h"

using namespace cocos2d;

extern "C"
{
    jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, void *reserved){
    JniHelper::setJavaVM(vm);
    return JNI_VERSION_1_4;
}

//...

void adjustScoreUpNow{
    PTPScoreController::scores().points.addCurrent(1); //This method <<<<<<<<<<
}
```

How can I call the `adjustScoreUpNow` from the `PTServicesBridge` Class?

Edit:
I was told by the engines support to do it this way. I was hoping there was an easy solution to calling the .cpp method from the Java class.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I don't think it is a duplication as the `main.cpp` is already used. So I just need to know how a method in that file can be called from the java class. Thank you for posting.

Comment: The answers to the linked question at the top of the page describe how to use JNI to do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

In `PTServicesBridge` define native java function. Something like:

```
private static native void  adjustScoreUpNow();
```

In `main.cpp` provide following implementation

```
extern "C" {
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_<full_package_name>_PTServicesBridge_adjustScoreUpNow(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz) {
   //Call native side conterpart 
   adjustScoreUpNow();     
}
}
```

Where `<full_package_name>` should be package name of `PTServicesBridge` with `_` instead of `.`.

For more info about how JNI works please take a look at [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html).

Comment: Thank you for posting. Unfortunately, I get the following error in the console: E/art: No implementation found for void `com.secrethq.utils.PTServicesBridge.adjustScoreUpNow() (tried Java_com_secrethq_utils_PTServicesBridge_adjustScoreUpNow and Java_com_secrethq_utils_PTServicesBridge_adjustScoreUpNow__)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM` Which is confusing because the method is there.

Comment: @Reanimation are you sure that your method get to the library .so? Extract native library from you apk or find it in your local build then execute `objdump -TC <lib.so location> | grep adjustScoreUpNow`. Please note that `objdump` should be from android NDK.

Comment: Well the generated Android Studio project already has a working main.cpp. So I’ve just added the function to that. As you can tell I have no experience with Android or Java. Thanks.

Comment: @Reanimation I understand that you use cocos2d and I even have generated project on my side. If `main.cpp` get built it should contain `Java_<full_package_name>_PTServicesBridge_adjustScoreUpNow` function. Right? But java cannot load it so probably `.so` library haven't been updated. In order to verify that provide result of command I've mentioned above. Otherwise I will not be able to help you

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I'm unable to find the location and I don't know how to execute that command. I think this is a sign to forget Android :(

Comment: Depends on how you load your library, you may need this in your java class: System.loadLibrary("native-lib");